# changing subsite template type

Tags: site-template, wiki, sub-site, team-sites, enterprise-wiki

I have a subsite in SharePoint that was originally created as a Publishing Enterprise Wiki. The problem with this is that all of the new pages added to the site are wiki pages, which in not ideal. As far as I know, the site templates are all basically the same thing but with different features enabled. What features do I need to modify to change the subsite from a wiki to a standard team site (so that added pages are just normal pages and not wiki pages).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want to migrate enterprise wiki site to a standard team site. As far as I know , there are no PowerShell script which can achieve this. When use `Import-SPWeb` command, The site or subsite that you are importing must have a template that matches the template of the site specified by Identity.

You can get the difference between both from below given URL.

[Enterprise Wiki vs Team Site in Sharepoint 2010](https://ranjanajain.wordpress.com/2011/05/27/enterprise-wiki-vs-team-site-in-sharepoint-2010/)

BTW you can refer below mentioned link & **check the answers** on the post. You might get some help from there.

[Migrate a SharePoint Team Wiki to an Enterprise Wiki](http://blogbaris.blogspot.com/2013/04/migrate-sharepoint-team-wiki-to.html)

Comment: thank you for your answer. now that I have additional info, I realize that what I want isn't necessarily to switch the site types, but to have newly created pages be standard wiki pages rather than enterprise wiki pages. For some reason, the subsite has both a site pages folder and a pages folder (while all other subsites only have a site pages folder). When I create a new page the subsite uses the pages list(?) which has a default type as an enterprise wiki page. Do you know how I can change the settings to default to the site pages list(?) to add standard wiki pages?

Comment: Deactivate the Publishing feature at my your wiki subsite. So you will get rid of the Pages library from site pages. In your case, If you try to create a new page from the page available under the pages library than it will create the page in pages library only.

Comment: If you try to create a page from wiki page (Site Pages) than it will create a wiki page for you within site pages.

Comment: You can check here for some problem...https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/febb84b1-5598-4a09-b18d-ba95c1761f77/deactivating-the-sharepoint-server-publishing-feature-at-my-enterprise-wiki-site-collection-will?forum=sharepointgeneral

Comment: so deactivating the Publishing feature did not do what I wanted it to do. I still have both a Pages and Site Pages folder, but now the "Add a Page" option is gone from the Site menu. I could already add standard wiki pages in the Site Pages list before (and still can), but what I wanted was for the Add a Page option to generate pages in the Site Pages list, which defaults to standard wiki pages that allow me to restructure the page layout. Now I don't have the option to quickly add a page without navigating to the Site Pages list